# leaflet map works sometime and some time it says initMap is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using leaflet map and googlemap tiles. The map works sometime and sometime it says "initMap is not a function".  And again if i refresh it, then it works fine again. Below is the code for reference. I am using firefox and chrome. The problem occurs mostly in chrome. Please, help me sort this out..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <?php $this->load->view('header/header')?>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAvAEGxWQfQ9qZkUkGGd7NwL8K5oRWZ-Ts&callback=iniMap"
    async defer></script>
    <script src="http://matchingnotes.com/javascripts/leaflet-google.js"></script>-->

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>mapcss/leaflet.css" />
   <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>mapjs/leaflet.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAvAEGxWQfQ9qZkUkGGd7NwL8K5oRWZ-Ts&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>mapjs/leaflet-google.js""></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>



  <style>
      .red{
          color: red;
      }
      .leaflet-map-pane {
          z-index: 2 !important;
      }

      .leaflet-google-layer {
          z-index: 1 !important;
      }
      #basemaps-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        z-index: 400;
        background: white;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      #button_setting{
        position:  absolute;
        top: 50px;
        right: 10px;
        z-index: 400;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      #show-button { 
        cursor: pointer; 
      }
      #hide-button { 
        cursor: pointer; 
        display: none; 
      }

      /*Some stylings to the buttons*/
      #show-button, #hide-button  { 
        color: #fff; 
        border-radius: 5px; 
        /*padding: 10px 50px; */
      }
      #show-button { 
        background: #28b463; 
        width: 60px;
      }
      #hide-button { 
        background: #af2303; 
        width: 60px;
      }

  </style>


</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">
  <?php $this->load->view('header/main_header')?>
  <?php  $this->load->view('menu/left_menu')?>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Vehicles

      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

       <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

      <div style="width:1100px; height:500px" id="map">
        <div id="basemaps-wrapper" class="leaflet-bar">
          <select name="basemaps" id="basemaps" onChange="changeBasemap(basemaps)">
            <option value="ROADMAP">ROADMAP</option>
            <option value="SATELLITE">SATELLITE</option>
            <option value="HYBRID">HYBRID</option>
            <option value="TERRAIN">TERRAIN</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div id="button_setting" class="leaflet-bar">
          <button id="show-button" onclick="stop()">Replay</button>
          <button id="hide-button" onclick="start()">Live</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="base" id="base" value="<?php echo $base; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="v_id" id="v_id" value="<?php echo $v_id; ?>">
    </div>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
      var googleLay;
      var googleLayer;
      var m;
      var baseurl = $("#base").val();
      var vehicle_id;
      var map;
      function initMap(){
        map = new L.Map('map');// {center: new L.LatLng(27.0696, 93.5508), zoom: 18});
        googleLayer = new L.Google('ROADMAP');
        map.addLayer(googleLayer);

        googleLay = googleLayer;
        m = map;

        vehicle_id = $("#v_id").val();
        get_location_data();
      }


      var marker;
      var polyline;

      var myIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: baseurl + 'images/recycling-truk.png',
        iconSize: [29, 24],
        iconAnchor: [9, 21],
        popupAnchor: [0, -14]
      });


      var timer = 0;
      var polylinePoints = [];
      var lat;
      var lng;
      function get_location_data(){
        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + "vehicle/get_location_data",
            dataType :"json", 
            data: {'v_id': vehicle_id},
            type: "post",
            success: function (data) {
              //alert(data);
              polylinePoints.length = 0;
              for (var key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    polylinePoints.push(new L.LatLng(data[key].latitude, data[key].longitude));
                    lat = data[key].latitude;
                    lng = data[key].longitude
                } 
              }
              set_polypoint();
            }
        });
        timer = setTimeout(get_location_data, 7000);
      }


      function set_polypoint(){
        var polylineOptions = {
          color: 'blue',
          weight: 6,
          opacity: 0.9
        };
        polyline = new L.Polyline(polylinePoints, polylineOptions);

        map.addLayer(polyline);
        polyline.addTo(map);

        if(marker){
          map.removeLayer(marker);
        }
        marker = L.marker([lat, lng], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup('<strong>Vehicle Code</strong><br>'+vehicle_id).openPopup();
        map.setView([lat, lng], 18);
      }

      function stop() {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = 0;
        }
        /*if(marker){
          map.removeLayer(marker);
        }

        if(polyline){
          map.removeLayer(polyline);
        }*/
        for (i in map._layers) {
            if (map._layers[i].options.format == undefined) {
                try {
                    map.removeLayer(map._layers[i]);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log("problem with " + e + map._layers[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        map.addLayer(googleLayer);
      }

      function start() {
        get_location_data();
      }

      function changeBasemap(basemaps){
            var basemap = basemaps.value;
            if (googleLay) {
              m.removeLayer(googleLay);
            }
            googleLay = new L.Google(basemap);
            m.addLayer(googleLay);
        }

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#show-button").click(function () {
         $("#hide-button").show()
         $("#show-button").hide()
        });
        $("#hide-button").click(function () {
         $("#show-button").show()
         $("#hide-button").hide()
        });
       });
</script>


    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
   <?php $this->load->view('footer/footer');?>


</div>

<!-- ./wrapper -->
</body>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<!-- Select2 -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: Please, someone say something.

Comment: Did you check javascript errors when it said "not a function" ?

Comment: yes in chrome it says                        js?key=AIzaSyAvAEGxW…allback=initMap:101 Uncaught 
Qb
message
:
"initMap is not a function"
name
:
"InvalidValueError"
stack
:

Comment: And if i refresh it sometime it works and sometime not and in Frefox it says "InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function"

Comment: Is there any problem with my code?